# assign arraylist value to textview

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to set the value from my arraylist to the textview

```
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayListPage1, arrayListPage2, arrayListPage3, arrayListPage4, arrayListPage5;

    arrayListPage1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(rangeMode);
    arrayListPage2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(rangeMode);
    arrayListPage3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(rangeMode);
    arrayListPage4 = new ArrayList<Integer>(rangeMode);
    arrayListPage5 = new ArrayList<Integer>(rangeMode);
    totalCardInPage = new int[totalPage+1];
    for(int j=1;j<=totalPage;j++){  
        int x=0;
        for(int i=1;i<=rangeMode;i++){
            if(binaryTable[i][j]==1){                   
                //maka i ada di page j
                cardInPage[j][x]=i;
                //array buat card di page 1
                if (j==1){
                    arrayListPage1.add(i);
                }else if(j==2){
                    arrayListPage2.add(i);
                }else if(j==3){
                    arrayListPage3.add(i);
                }else if(j==4){
                    arrayListPage4.add(i);
                }else if(j==5){
                    arrayListPage5.add(i);
                }
                x++;                    
            }
        }
        System.out.println("page-"+j+" jumlah kartu:"+x);
        totalCardInPage[j]=x;
    }
    System.out.println("List page 1 "+arrayListPage1);
    System.out.println("List page 2 "+arrayListPage2);
    System.out.println("List page 3 "+arrayListPage3);
    System.out.println("List page 4 "+arrayListPage4);
    System.out.println("List page 5 "+arrayListPage5);
    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    if (arrayListPage1[0]!=null){

        text1.setText(arrayListPage1[0]);
    }
    else{
        text1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (arrayListPage1[1]!=null){
        text1.setText(arrayListPage1[1]);
    }
    else{
        text1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

but I got an error when I'm trying to set the arraylist value to my textview. The error said because I'm using arraylist so I cannot assign the value to the textview

anyone know how to fix this?

thanks

Comment: show your logcat file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because You set Integer value to Your TextView and TextView finds String from resources. Convert Your Integer value to String.

For example:

```
text1.setText(arrayListPage1.get(0).toString());
```

or simple:

```
text1.setText(arrayListPage1.get(0) + "");
```

Comment: the error still said "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList<Integer>"

Comment: You need to use get() method instead. Also my previous information is correct.