# Can not assign string data from arraylist to textview

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` in my `mainActivity` which stores `String` data. After declaring the `ArrayList` data are inserted from a database to the `ArrayList`. then when user clicks any element on `ListView`. I am trying to get data from the `ArrayList` using index value. Below is the code I am using.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("rice");
list.add("wheat");
```

Then I try to get data like

```
String data=list.get(0);
mtTextView.setText(data); //error is shown on this line
```

Where is the error and why I am getting the error. I cant find any wrong with the code

I followed below thread

[assign arraylist value to textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216577/assign-arraylist-value-to-textview)

It tells to convert to string (as they had int value) but already i have string variable.

Comment: What's the error that is shown?

Comment: Post more relevant code.

Comment: Show the code u are loading data from database..

Comment: The only problem in the above code could be that mtTextView is not properly initialized or the list has null elements.
Provide more code or add dummy values to setText to validate further.

Comment: did you define the textview properly

Comment: Post the error you're getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you initialise every thing properly. This is my code.

*MainActivity.class*

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("rice");
        list.add("wheat");

        String data=list.get(0);
        textview.setText(data);
    }
}
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.codephillip.intmain.cpgenerator.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView mtTextView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
String data=list.get(0);
mtTextView.setText(data);
```